# Get versions from item

Tags: csom

I am trying to get all versions from an list item and tried following:

```
$listName = "VersionHistoryStatistics"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "xxx"

$ctx= Get-PnPContext
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$item = $list.GetItemById(1);
$versions = $item.Versions
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.Load($item)
$ctx.Load($versions)
```

Error: Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1". Any idea on whats causing this? Its the last line throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it was a mismatch between two PnP versions. After uninstalling all PnP versions and reinstalling it worked.